# SQL Server SUM function with single precision

Tags: c#, sql-server, aggregate-functions

I am converting an older piece of software that uses single precision values to do calculations. My new application is written in C# and uses SQL Server. As part of this conversion I really need calculated values to match in order to prove out the new system.

I would like to use the SUM function in SQL Server to calculate some values, but according to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187810.aspx) and observed behavior of that function (SUM), the result is being calculated using double precision.

If I return individual values as single precision to my application and then sum them up in C# (using Single) my values match the old system. But in most cases the overhead (time required) of doing this is going to tough to take.

So my question is... Is there a way to SUM in SQL Server (2014) that will force single precision values (**real** in SQL Server) to be used in the calculations?

Oh and the values will range from very large to very small so I don't believe DECIMAL(n,m) will work.

Comment: You can write and deploy your own "SUM" aggregate function, where the code to calculate the sum would be in C#. Check out CLR User-Defined Aggregates http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131057.aspx

Comment: Sum() returns float to protect against overflow.  You said you have some very large values.  What data type does the current calculation result in?

Comment: IMHO CLR function is overkill for this problem

Comment: @CrimsonKing The CLR user-defined aggregate worked great and gives the control I was looking for. If you post this as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write and deploy your own "SUM" aggregate function, where the code to calculate the sum would be in C#. Check out [CLR User-Defined Aggregates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131057.aspx).

```
[Serializable]
[Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlUserDefinedAggregate(
    Format.Native,
    IsInvariantToDuplicates = false,
    IsInvariantToNulls = true,
    IsInvariantToOrder = true,
    IsNullIfEmpty = true,
    Name = "SumReal")]
public struct SumReal
{
    private Single sum;

    public void Init()
    {
        sum = 0;
    }

    public void Accumulate(SqlSingle Value)
    {
        if (!Value.IsNull)
        {
            sum += (Single)Value;
        }
    }

    public void Merge(SumReal Group)
    {
        sum += (Single)Group.sum;
    }

    public SqlSingle Terminate()
    {
        // Put your code here
        return sum;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
SUM(CAST(MyColumn as real))
```

`SUM` returns float when base column is real, but number could be as in old system.

Comment: No, casting expression values does not change the resulting data type. The documentation indicates float or real will result in a float value. That's the basic question, is there another option where I could force calculations to remain in the original data type (real).

Comment: Return value will be double, but result should be result of summation of real numbers, not doubles. You can cast result to real too, if it is matters. cast(sum(cast (MyColumn as real)) as real)

Comment: Even if I cast expression values to real the SUM function is performing a summation of doubles. I can tell this because casting expression values as float or real ((CAST MyCol AS FLOAT) and (CAST MyCol AS REAL) results in the exact same value.

Comment: In execution plan I see that SQL Server do convert to real(24) before aggregation. It is single precision. If I do CAST(MyColumn as float) I see conversion to float(53), double precision. BTW what is type of MyCol in your table?

Comment: Take a look on this [script](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bb8b3/1). SUM + CAST does produce correct result. As if you'd SUM column of reals.